# Grid Errors When Displaying Skills for Portfolio in React

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to figure out how to map a Grid for each of my "skills" panels for my Portfolio. The skills are being pulled and iterated over from the arrays you see at the top of the file below, here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    color:'green',
    alignContent:"center"
  },
  paper: {
    height: 150,
    width: 100
  },

 
}));

const frontEnd =['Django','Reactjs','Javascript','HTML','CSS']
const backEnd =['Python','Typescript','Nodejs','Express']
const databases =['MongoDB','MySQL']
const tools = ['AWS','AWS-CDK','Docker','AWS-Lambda','Figma','Microservices','Kubernetes']

const SpacingGrid = (props) => {
  // const [spacing] = React.useState(2);
  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <div>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Body align="center">
          Front-End
        </Body>
        {frontEnd.map((skill)=>(
          <Body align="center" key={skill}>
            {skill}
          </Body>
        ))}﻿
        <Paper className={classes.control}>
          <Grid container justify="center">
        <Grid item>{props.children}</Grid>
        <Grid item> </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
            ))}
            </div>

  
  );
};

export default SpacingGrid;
```

so I am trying to create a separate panel for each of the arrays and give it a title such as "Front-End Skills", "Back-End Skills". Thank you all for your help!

Comment: So what seems to the problem? Is not displaying correctly? I mean where should the troubleshooting begin?

Comment: so yes it is not displaying at all and when it was it was putting each skill in it's own rectangle horizontally across the page